# RTK Query data provided by useMutation() undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I can't seem to find an answer to this specific case and I am somewhat new to whole JS world, so would appreciate explanation of following:

I am using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) and RTK Query, all works there. I have it setup, I am making a POST request with form data body type and response is Blob image.

I followed docs so I am pretty sure my setup is good.

However when doing the following:

```js
const [postSomeData, { data, isLoading, error, isSuccess }] =
  usePostSomeDataMutation();
```

Then on button press or some action ....

```js
await postSomeData({
  "blah":"blah"
});
       
if (isSuccess) {
  const myData = data; // undefined
}
```

`data` from this function is always undefined. And yes I always check for `isSuccess`, `isLoading`, `isError` before accessing the `data` and it always returns undefined.

One thing to note is I added `responseHandler` to my apiSlice which takes `response.blob` and converts it to base64 string.

So by my logic this `data` should be equal to the base64 string and yet it is not.

What actually works is if I do the following

```js
const [postSomeData, { data, isLoading, error, isSuccess }] =
  usePostSomeDataMutation();
```

Then on button press or some action...

```js
const myData = await postSomeData({
  "blah":"blah"
}).unwrap(); // has my data
```

And in this case I get the actual response data I am failing to get from the "above" `data` value. Why is this the case and what is the purpose of `data` from `useMutation` if I have to define it myself anyway?

Comment: Have you tried to log the `data` in the render? is it always undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Redux-Toolkit Query (RTK, RTKQ) all queries and mutations start out initially uncalled with uncached responses, i.e. there is not any `data` to provide to components, e.g. `data` is undefined.

```js
const [
  postSomeData,
  {
    data, // <-- undefined until first successful response is cached
    isLoading,
    error,
    isSuccess
  }
] = usePostSomeDataMutation();
```

It seems what you are not understanding here is [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
> with references to its surrounding state (the **lexical
> environment**). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer
> function's scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are
> created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

In the first example you have closed over the initially undefined `data` value in the callback scope, so it will *never* become defined with the mutation's response value.

```js
const theCallback = async () => {
  await postSomeData({ "blah": "blah" });
   
  if (isSuccess) {
    const myData = data; // undefined from closure
  }
};
```

The reason the second example does work is because the callback awaits and unwraps the resolved Promise returned from the trigger function which is the mutation response value (*or an error!!*). Note here you should also surround the asynchronous logic in a `try/catch` as any thrown exceptions and Rejected Promises will also be unwrapped.

Example:

```js
const theCallback = async () => {
  try {
    const myData = await postSomeData({ "blah": "blah" }).unwrap();
    ...
  } catch(error) {
    ... catch any thrown exceptions or rejected Promises
  }
};
```

For more details/explanation of the mutation trigger's return value review:

- [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results)

> What is the purpose of `data` from `useMutation` if I have to define
> it myself anyway?

The purpose of declaring/destructuring `data` from the hook is so that it is declared and in-scope in the React function component body, e.g. it can be used to render JSX from. If you didn't need it in the function component body then there would be no need to declare/destructure it from `usePostSomeDataMutation`.